# How to add a ng-model property to a object in the Angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I do not understand why the the uuid and datetime is not binding from my controller to my view. It isn't necessary though, I can add them to the object in the controller. problem is I'm not sure how to do that. I need to add the .dt & .CivilCaseId to the newCivilCase. thanks

```
  //Generate Unique Id
$scope.newCivil = [];
$scope.newCivil.CivilCaseId = uuid2.newuuid();
console.log($scope.newCivil.CivilCaseId);
//Todays Date
$scope.newCivil.dt = new Date();
console.log($scope.newCivil.dt);


//Post Civil Case
$scope.newCivil = new Civil();
$scope.addCivilCase = function () {
    $scope.newCivil.$save(function () {
        console.log($scope.newCivil); $state.go('home');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems in your first line, you set

```
$scope.newCivial = [];
```

But after that, you set

```
$scope.newCivil = new Civil(); //return object previous 'newCivil' is covered by this statement.
```

Suggest you to change your code into this:

```
//Generate Unique Id
$scope.newCivil = new Civil();

$scope.newCivil.CivilCaseId = uuid2.newuuid();
$scope.newCivil.dt = new Date();
console.log($scope.newCivil.dt);

//Post Civil Case
$scope.addCivilCase = function () {
    $scope.newCivil.$save(function () {
        console.log($scope.newCivil); $state.go('home');
    });
};
```